# Ajax url parameters as a variable. How?

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, parameters

Is there a way to set a ajax url with a variable?

```
function ajaxDialog() {
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    DataType: "html"
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking since in your example, you are using a variable to specify the URL.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. Do you want to pass URL parameters in your AJAX post? Or, are you looking to put a URL string inside the URL variable?

Comment: I was in doubt about the variable scope. Fiddle already answered the questions. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use variables for the parameters.

```
var url="";
var var1 = "somevalue"

function ajaxDialog() {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data:{
       data1: var1   
         }
      });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/pGJbY/)